# Is is possible to substitute the matched pattern in vim?

Tags: regex, vim, pattern-matching, substitution

Every time before I replace `pattern1` with `pattern2`, I usually use `/pattern1` to confirm  the regex is the right one. When doing the actual substitution, however, I have to use `:%s/pattern1/pattern2/g`(Suppose I need to do the global replacement). This is annoying and may fail due to typos.

So is there a convenient way to substitute the matched `pattern1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// is last search
`:%s//replacement/g` will do what you want.

however you could also think about `%s/pattern1/pattern2/gc` or `%s/p1/p2/gn`

Answer (score 1):

The null string in the first half of the s command defaults to the last searched pattern.

So

```
g/fred/s//mary/g
```

changes all instances of fred to mary.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an empty pattern:

```
:%s//pattern2/g
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that:

:.,.+3s//repl/g

should replace every occurence of the current pattern in the next 3 lines with repl.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `:%s/pattern/replace/c` (notice the trailing `c`) and vim will ask for confirmation.